# syntax error, expected end statement on QTP

Tags: hp-uft

```
Set obju=description.Create()
obju("name").value="user"
obju("html tag").value="input"
Arow=Browser("creationtime:=0").page("title:=.*").webedit(obju).set DataTable.Value("user",Global)
Arow=datatable.GetRowCount
For i = 1 To Arow Step 1
datatable.SetCurrentRow (i)
```

Next
its giving me error "The test run cannot continue due to a syntax error.

Expected end of statement"

anyone know whats going on?

Comment: Do you have a `Next` at the end of your `For` block?

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
Arow=Browser("creationtime:=0").page("title:=.*").webedit(obju).set DataTable.Value("user",Global)
```

you're assigning the return value from the `webedit(obju).set` procedure to the variable `Arow`. If you're doing this in VBScript then the arguments for the procedure need to be put in parentheses.

Following the logic of your code I'm not sure if you're intending to save a return value from the `set` procedure, in which case just take out assigning to the variable:

```
Browser("creationtime:=0").page("title:=.*").webedit(obju).set DataTable.Value("user",Global)
```

Similarly, in the for loop, the `datatable.SetCurrentRow (i)` procedure should be called as

```
datatable.SetCurrentRow i
```